# Integrating p5.sound.js in Meteor: p5.AudioIn() is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, audio, meteor, p5.js

I try to integrate the `p5.sound.js` library in Meteor 1.2.1

I want to record Audio in my template with p5js features, but I always get an error message. Let me show you step by step what I do:

1. Integrating the p5 libraries

I have put the `p5.min.js` and `p5.sound.js` into the Meteor folder `/client/compatibility/`

2. The audio recording sketch

I want to get started first with the p5 standard [Audio Recoding example](https://p5js.org/examples/examples/Sound__Record_Save_Audio.php) and just redesigned the code a bit by defining a global variable `var sketch1;` saved in a file called `global.js` in the Meteor `lib` folder whereas the whole sketch `sketch1.js` is just saved in the `client` folder. This is how my sketch looks like:

```js
/////////////////
///p5js tryaudio recording
/////////////////
sketch1 = function(s){
  var mic, recorder, soundFile;

  var state = 0; // mousePress will increment from Record, to Stop, to Play

  s.setup = function() {
    s.createCanvas(400,400);
    s.background(200);
    s.fill(0);
    s.text('Enable mic and click the mouse to begin recording', 20, 20);

    // create an audio in
    mic = new p5.AudioIn();

    // users must manually enable their browser microphone for recording to work properly!
    mic.start();

    // create a sound recorder
    recorder = new p5.SoundRecorder();

    // connect the mic to the recorder
    recorder.setInput(mic);

    // create an empty sound file that we will use to playback the recording
    soundFile = new p5.SoundFile();
  }

  s.mousePressed = function() {
    // use the '.enabled' boolean to make sure user enabled the mic (otherwise we'd record silence)
    if (state === 0 && mic.enabled) {

      // Tell recorder to record to a p5.SoundFile which we will use for playback
      recorder.record(soundFile);

      s.background(255,0,0);
      s.text('Recording now! Click to stop.', 20, 20);
      state++;
    }

    else if (state === 1) {
      recorder.stop(); // stop recorder, and send the result to soundFile

      s.background(0,255,0);
      s.text('Recording stopped. Click to play & save', 20, 20);
      state++;
    }

    else if (state === 2) {
      soundFile.play(); // play the result!
      saveSound(soundFile, 'mySound.wav'); // save file
      state++;
    }
  }
}
```

3. Integrating the sketch into the template

My template is called `tryaudiolist.html` and it's just integrating the sketch in a `<div>` tag with the id="s" like the following:

```html
<template name="tryaudiolist">
   <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-12">
      <p>the sketch works here: </p>
     </div>
     <div id="s"></div>
    </div>

   </div>
</template>
```

4. The `client.js` file

in the `client.js` file I make the sketch to render into the template with the Meteor onRendered() function. Here is the code snippet:

```js
Template.tryaudiolist.onRendered(function() {
     console.log("entering onCreated");
     var myp5 = new p5(sketch1, "s");
    
})
```

5. The error in console

When I try to run the app, the code gets rendered and the canvas builds up by p5js as expected:

```html
<div id="s">
  <canvas id="defaultCanvas0" data-hidden="true" width="400" height="400"     style="visibility: hidden; width: 400px; height: 400px;"></canvas>
</div>
```

However, when the onRendered() function is entered (see my console.log statement `client.js:37 entering onCreated`) it complains about the `p5.AudioIn()` method:

```js
sketch1.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
client.js:37 entering onCreated
debug.js:41 Exception from Tracker afterFlush function:
debug.js:41 Error: error connecting to node: [object GainNode]
    at ScriptProcessorNode.AudioNode.connect (p5.sound.js:2976)
    at new p5.Amplitude (p5.sound.js:2229)
    at new p5.AudioIn (p5.sound.js:6327)
    at s.setup (sketch1.js:17)
    at .<anonymous> (p5.min.js:5)
    at .<anonymous> (p5.min.js:5)
    at new o (p5.min.js:5)
    at .<anonymous> (client.js:38)
    at template.js:116
    at Function.Template._withTemplateInstanceFunc (template.js:457)
sketch1.js:34 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'enabled' of undefined
```

Herein, `s.setup (sketch1.js:17)` refers to my object definition `mic = new p5.AudioIn();` which  is not excepted. Same in `sketch1.js:34 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'enabled' of undefined` it can't recognise `mic` being instantiated as a `p5.AudioIn()` object. And finally in `.<anonymous> (client.js:38)` it's the p5 object that the console is complaining about.

6. Summary

As you can see, I tried to implement the standard p5 [Record Save Audio example](https://p5js.org/examples/examples/Sound__Record_Save_Audio.php) in Meteor. But not yet successful.

I don't know how I can solve this? Is it a referencing error? Do I probably use the wrong syntax to access the object?

Comment: Is there more to your sketch1.js file that you haven't shown here?  I'm not getting that error message in my console using this code.

Comment: No, actually, the sketch1.js  here is complete.

Comment: But I didn't show you all of the console's error messages. Like there is a "p5.js's exp() function error" (p5 wants me to initialize all var in setup() --> this is what I do) and a SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in sketch1.js 
However, I can't explain those ones. Even why they occurr. I think my syntax is clean and it all derives from the AudioIn() issue. But please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @MarkLeiber: in fact, Mark, you have revealed my mistake. Thank you! I still had a head.html file in my client folder with the following referencing
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.5.0/addons/p5.sound.min.js"></script>
This means I tried to reference to the p5.sound library in two different ways in my app. Now as I removed the head.html, the basic example works. However, I wasn't referring correctly to the saveSound () method. The correct way is to call s.saveSound().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my mistakes, finally.

1. I still had a reference to the CDN online repository for the `p5.sound.min.js` in my `head.html` file in the `client` folder which I used in my first attempt to integrate p5js before I switched to implementing the Meteor onRendered() function. By removing this reference, the `sketch1.js` finally got rendered correctly.
2. the `saveSound(soundFile, 'mySound.wav')` method wasn't referenced correctly. I need to call it through the p5 object with `s.saveSound(soundFile, 'mySound.wav')`